# What does my_str=i +my_str do here in python?

Tags: python, operators, assignment-operator

Below is a code reversing a string using a loop. What does  `my_str=i+my_str` do here?

```
def reverse(s):
  my_str = ""
  for i in s:
    my_str = i + my_str
  return my_str
  
s = "Thisismyquestion"
  
print ("The original string  is : ",end="")
print (s)
  
print ("The reversed string(using loops) is : ",end="")
print (reverse(s))
```

Comment: concating the next one with the prev one.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I still don't understand how exactly does this assignment operator my_str=i+my_str works.  I know it is a += operator, but when put it into code I get confused

Comment: @DavidMeu which one is the next one and which one is the previous one?

Comment: It isn't a `+=` operator. It's a `+` operator. You compute `i + my_str`, and then you say that `my_str` should become that result. Why is this confusing?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it supposes to return a reversed string of "Thisismyquestion" and it does

Comment: Okay. You see how that line of code is *inside a loop*? Try to understand what will happen the first time it runs, the second time, etc. Make sure you understand what the value of `i` will be each time though the loop. Also, **look up and follow a tutorial**.

Comment: @Maibaozi see below answer

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Isn't my_str an empty one? Is the my_str on the left side the same thing as the right side one? Once it involves a loop I get confused...

Comment: @Maibaozi learn how to use a debugger, then inspect your variables step-by-step and you'll see what happens during each iteration of the loop. If string concatenation confuses you, you should go back to reading tutorials, this is just too low-level to explain on StackOverflow.

Comment: "Once it involves a loop I get confused" A loop is just doing the same thing multiple times. So *think about what happens the first time*. What is `my_str` *after doing that the first time? So, that will affect what happens the second time, because of how it is used.

Comment: ok I see and thank you@KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 1):

Please use the code block the help with formatting. You can click {} on the toolbar when you write question/answer.

Regarding your question :

First loop aka first letter of your string  `i = T`  :

```
my_str = ""         # it's empty
my_str = i + my_str # we combine T with an empty string
print(my_str)       # T
```

Second loop  `i = h`  :

```
my_str = "T"         # my_str is still T from first loop
my_str = i + my_str  # we combine h with the T string
print(my_str)        # hT
```

Third loop  `i = i`  :

```
my_str = "hT"         # my_str is still hT from second loop
my_str = i + my_str   # we combine i with the hT string
print(my_str)         # ihT
```

Fourth loop  `i = s`  :

```
my_str = "ihT"         # my_str is still ihT from third loop
my_str = i + my_str    # we combine s with the ihT string
print(my_str)          # sihT
```

Here is your code, formatted, in which I added a print in every loop to help understand :

```
def reverse(s):
    print()
    my_str = ""
    for i in s:
        my_str = i + my_str
        print(my_str)
    return my_str


s = "Thisismyquestion"

print("The original string is : ", end="")
print(s)

print("The reversed string(using loops) is : ", end="")
print(reverse(s))
```

Output :

```
The original string is : Thisismyquestion
The reversed string(using loops) is : 
T
hT
ihT
sihT
isihT
sisihT
msisihT
ymsisihT
qymsisihT
uqymsisihT
euqymsisihT
seuqymsisihT
tseuqymsisihT
itseuqymsisihT
oitseuqymsisihT
noitseuqymsisihT
noitseuqymsisihT
```

Comment: Thank you !! This is so helpful!! @Jerome Verdoni